# Assignment operator gives 'no suitable user-defined conversion' error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I have a `CDateTime` class with the following method:

```
CDateTime& operator=(const COleDateTime& datetime)
{
    SetDateTime(&datetime);
    return *this;
}
```

But it doesn't appear to be working.

[image]

Can someone tell me what I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing, not assigning, `dtStart` and `dtEnd` variables. To make the initialization work, you need this constructor: `CDateTime(const COleDateTime& datetime)`.

Or, if `CDateTime` has default constructor, you can split the initialization into declaration and assignment:

```
CDateTime dtStart; dtStart = dlg.m_dtStartDate;
```

Comment: D'oh! Yup, I'm initializing. Thanks.